# Parser or app to mark up HTML code for syntax highlighting

Tags: javascript, html, css, syntax-highlighting, epub

I'm hoping to create a document in ePub format with a lot of HTML and CSS code samples. Layout options are quite limited with ePub - it's mostly XHTML with primitive CSS, but there's no support for JS syntax utils like [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/). I'd like to format my code blocks nicely like they do on Stackoverflow, wrapping keywords, attribute names, attribute values, strings and tags in spans with different CSS classes, and encoding the tags with HTML escape sequences so they get displayed as code in the HTML, not as parsed and rendered HTML.

This is the kind of code I'd like to render nicely in my HTML document. If you view this block in developer tools, you'll see the kind of modification Stackoverflow makes to style the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-gb">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="intro" id="intro">Lorem ipsum</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone recommend a way of parsing this kind of HTML code and spitting out the escaped, CSSed markup? Is there an easy way I could do this with JS?

Comment: If you want to produce EPUB2, JS is out of question. JS support in EPUB3 is good basically in iBooks only, and I would discourage using it. What about using a static (X)HTML compiler --- like Jekyll with a syntax highlighter (say, pygments) --- which is able to output the escaped, CSSed, static XHTML? What format do your doc source files use? If you use a markdown-like format, I think it is the best approach given the current state of the art.

Comment: Forgot: pygments (but there are several other similar "static" syntax highlighters) is here: http://pygments.org/

Comment: Great, thanks Alberto, I'll look into Jekyll + pygments. I'll be starting with either html or some kind of text.

Comment: Not a JS answer, sorry. And I don't know what OS you're running. But if you can run it, GVIM "save as HTML" under the tools menu does what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll give it a try! I'd be on OSX I guess.